# Cross Origin $http Requests | Resource

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, slim

So I was writing an app when I got across this issue.

**This is the PHP : Slimframework Corresponding :**

```
$app->delete('/products/:id',function($id) use($app){
    $db = new mysqli('notsocoolhost','verycooluser','verycoolpassword','verycooldatabase');
    $db->query("DELETE from products WHERE id='$id'");
});
```

I removed the part where I confirm that you can actually delete it from the database.

**This is Angular.JS :**

```
   $scope.del = function(product){
    $http({
       method: "DELETE",
       url: baseUrl + product.id
    }).success(function(){ ......  //Returns 0 -> WTF?
```

This buddy here returns in error status : 0

and this one below returns 405:

```
$scope.delete(baseUrl + product.id).success ... //Returns 405 : Method Not Allowed
```

To sum it up, I added couple of tests on Hurl.it and the RESTApi from Slimframework is fully functioning. which leaves it as Angular.js problem ? I guess?

**UPDATE:**

After further inspection I've revealed the following:

1) Mysteriously the : Request Method (Field by Firefox) is OPTIONS.

2) Access-Control-Request-Method : "DELETE"

3) Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT"

Comment: start by inspecting the actual request in browser console network tab

Comment: Just did so, ODD Thing.. I find that the Request Method shown by Firefox is OPTIONS while Access-Control-Request-Method is DELETE and Access-Control-Allow-Methods is GET POST DELETE PUT

Comment: i guess your app and your server are not in the same domain

Comment: You are correct, they are not using the same domain, But the server is replying the right headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin : "*"

Comment: I mean my api is in subdomain not a directory, which activates CORS

Comment: @أنيسبوهاشم I've changed the topic of this question according to your enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this serves people in the future.

Back to basics, having trouble sending $http requests in cross-origin requests has nothing to do with the server nor Angular.js.

If you are like me hosting your webapp on:

`https:\\www.beautifuldomain.com`

and your API on :

`https:\\api.beautifuldomain.com`

Whenever you try to perform a request between Webapp and API you are performing Cross-Origin Request.

> What does it mean?

It means that your message will be considered as Cross-Origin and it will be preflighted.

> Preflighted?

It means that when you use any method other than GET,HEAD or POST.
Also POST if used to send request data with `Content-Type` other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain, e.g.`

It will be sent as method: `OPTIONS`. -- That is preflighted.

> OK, OK I understand, but what do i do?

Now that is clear we have two options to move on:

**First Option:**

Leaving the web-server structure as is i.e:

`www.example.com` -> Angular Web-App

`api.example.com` -> API - subdomain

**FOR POST:**
And add a transformRequest setting to $httpProvider like so:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
```

(Remember preflighted, well it does allow us to send `x-www-form-urlencoded`.)

What is left from there is make sure you set your data in x-www-form-urlencoded format looks like so :

`name=Andy&nickname=RainbowWarrior&....`

**FOR DELETE:**

This one is a bit more complicated since you have to do some server side tweak.

If you are using Slimframework for PHP like I do, all you got to do is:

```
$response = $app->response();
$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
$app->options('/path/to/resource',function(){}); // This one just so you can accept OPTIONS it does nothing.


$app->delete('/path/to/resource',function()
{//your delete code is here 
});
```

Now whenever you try to perform `DELETE` from angular you will see on `XHR` tab in w/e browser you are using that There is `OPTIONS` request that was made and right after `DELETE`.

**Second Option:**
 Much less of a headache .
 Move your API into the same domain i.e
 `www.example.com` - Webapp
 `www.example.com/api` - API

And you are protected from all of that above.
This took me 7 hours of research I hope it will help you guys and save you time!.

Comment: i think you can just allow option method like so `$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');` instead of defining a route for option request.